# Flutter Android TV app is rejected because "crashes after launch" but it works correctly on the emulator and android tv. Do you have any suggestions?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, android-tv, flutter-android

I have published an app for Android TV. The app works correctly on the emulator and android tv I don't see any errors.
The result of the check from Play Store is:

Eligibility issues by version

Crashing after launchYour app crashes after launch, which means we cannot review your app for Android TV inclusion. Please refer to our TV Activity documentation for details.

We have added the same configuration in our app like: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48109

Have you had a similar experience that you were able to solve? What have you done?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Hi did you got any solution?

Comment: @user998405  No we are still try

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? I face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play test apps automatically, you can achieve same result by releasing an internal testing app and check the `pre launch report` to see which TV is it crashing on and what is the stack trace of the error, also you can see a video of the crash on real TV.

Comment: We have to check the real-tv and emulator it's working fine.

Comment: Pre launch report will show w the specific tv model that they are using and show you a video of the test.

Comment: I face the same issues, but pre-lunch report doesn't contain any TV device.

Comment: @ilbets you can use Firebase Test Lab https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/c55af0f438f6ddea6a94e26962ea52ba

Comment: Tried, there are only 2 TV devices and both doesn't support app architecture